# NoClassDefFoundError: OsgiDefaultCamelContext using Apache ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I created simple bundle:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private CamelContext camelContext;
    private CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        csv.setDelimiter('|');
        csv.setQuoteDisabled(true);
        camelContext = new OsgiDefaultCamelContext(bundleContext);
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file://./in/csv?charset=windows-1251")
                        .unmarshal(csv)
                        .process(exchange -> {
                          //do smth
                        });

            }
        });
        camelContext.start();
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}
```

I using `Apache ServiceMix`. I install bundles:

```
karaf@root>feature:install camel-csv
karaf@root>bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-core-osgi/2.16.5
```

But, when I start my bundle, I have error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/core/osgi/OsgiDefaultCamelContext
    at ru.camel.csv.Activator.start(Activator.java:19)
```

But why? In `karaf` console I see:

```
222 | Active    |  50 | 2.16.5                             | camel-csv
223 | Active    |  50 | 1.1.0                              | Apache Commons CSV
224 | Resolved  |  80 | 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT                     | csv
228 | Active    |  80 | 2.16.5                             | camel-core-osgi
```

Bundle `camel-core-osgi` contains class `OsgiDefaultCamelContext`. Why I get this error?

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>ru.camel</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.camel.test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>csv</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>osgi-bundle</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <instructions>
                                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                                <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                                <Import-Package>org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiDefaultCamelContext</Import-Package>
                                <Bundle-Activator>ru.camel.csv.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                            </instructions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the imports of your bundle.

Every bundle has to declare which packages (classes) it wants to import. Your bundle probably did not declare to import the package `OsgiDefaultCamelContext` is in.

Imports are defined in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of your bundle. Depending on your build tool this file might be created automatically during the build. Otherwise, you have to write that yourself, although I would highly recommend looking at a tool that does this automatically during the build.

In your `pom.xml`change the configuration of the `Import-Package` statement of the `maven-bundle-plugin` to:

```
<Import-Package>org.apache.camel.core.osgi.*;*</Import-Package>
```

Comment: It's not work. I add in my `pom.xml` maven-bundle-plugin and `<Import-Package>org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiDefaultCamelContext</Import-Package>`. I get error: `Error starting bundle 224: Unable to resolve csv [224](R 224.1): missing requirement [csv [224](R 224.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiDefaultCamelContext) Unresolved requirements: [[csv [224](R 224.1)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiDefaultCamelContext)]`

Comment: @All_Safe The configuration is called `Import-Package`. You are add the whole FQDN of the class itself and not the package. I updated my answer. Have a look.